# HeifDecoderImpl causes 'decStrong() called too many times'

Tags: android, image, memory-management, heif

My Android app "Photo Compare" (https://github.com/sniederb/photocompare) uses a "Subsampling Scale Image View" (from Dave Morrissey) to display images, and allows zooming and panning. This almost always works well, but on Android 11 with HEIC images, the activity crashes as soon as I zoom in.

The aborting thread is

```
    runtime.cc:655] Aborting thread:
    runtime.cc:655] "HeifDecode" prio=6 tid=32 Native
    runtime.cc:655]   | group="" sCount=0 dsCount=0 flags=0 obj=0x12c40020 self=0xe9022210
    runtime.cc:655]   | sysTid=18958 nice=-2 cgrp=top-app sched=0/0 handle=0xc6e561e0
    runtime.cc:655]   | state=R schedstat=( 98486663 91130505 137 ) utm=2 stm=7 core=2 HZ=100
    runtime.cc:655]   | stack=0xc6d5b000-0xc6d5d000 stackSize=1008KB
    runtime.cc:655]   | held mutexes= "abort lock"
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #00 pc 00542d9e  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool)+110)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #01 pc 006a0897  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+1015)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #02 pc 0069a171  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const+65)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #03 pc 006522c5  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::AbortState::DumpThread(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, art::Thread*) const+53)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #04 pc 00639abb  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2587)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #05 pc 00025a23  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libartbase.so (std::__1::__function::__func<void (*)(char const*), std::__1::allocator<void (*)(char const*)>, void (char const*)>::operator()(char const*&&)+35)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #06 pc 0001588f  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+79)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #07 pc 00006dbd  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+285)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #08 pc 000102a2  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::RefBase::decStrong(void const*) const+146)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #09 pc 00004de4  /system/lib/libheif.so (android::HeifDecoderImpl::decodeAsync()+436)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #10 pc 00004c23  /system/lib/libheif.so (android::HeifDecoderImpl::DecodeThread::threadLoop()+35)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #11 pc 00015116  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+374)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #12 pc 00098fee  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+174)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #13 pc 000147d9  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+457)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #14 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100)
    runtime.cc:655]   native: #15 pc 00078567  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+71)
    runtime.cc:655]   (no managed stack frames)
```

and the crash report states

```
2021-01-09 14:12:53.736 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG: *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
2021-01-09 14:12:53.736 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG: Build fingerprint: 'google/sdk_gphone_x86_arm/generic_x86_arm:11/RSR1.201013.001/6903271:userdebug/dev-keys'
2021-01-09 14:12:53.736 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG: Revision: '0'
2021-01-09 14:12:53.737 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG: ABI: 'x86'
2021-01-09 14:12:53.737 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG: Timestamp: 2021-01-09 14:12:53+0100
2021-01-09 14:12:53.737 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG: pid: 18085, tid: 18958, name: HeifDecode  >>> ch.want.imagecompare <<<
2021-01-09 14:12:53.737 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG: uid: 10153
2021-01-09 14:12:53.737 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG: signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -1 (SI_QUEUE), fault addr --------
2021-01-09 14:12:53.738 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG: Abort message: 'decStrong() called on 0xc7e43d10 too many times'
2021-01-09 14:12:53.738 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:     eax 00000000  ebx 000046a5  ecx 00004a0e  edx 00000006
2021-01-09 14:12:53.738 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:     edi f4a5681e  esi c6e559c0
2021-01-09 14:12:53.738 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:     ebp f7517b90  esp c6e55968  eip f7517b99
2021-01-09 14:12:53.744 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG: backtrace:
2021-01-09 14:12:53.745 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #00 pc 00000b99  [vdso] (__kernel_vsyscall+9)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.745 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #01 pc 0005ad68  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (syscall+40) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.745 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #02 pc 00076511  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (abort+209) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.745 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #03 pc 00639a4d  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+2477) (BuildId: 8191579dfafff37a5cbca70f9a73020f)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.745 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #04 pc 00025a23  /apex/com.android.art/lib/libartbase.so (std::__1::__function::__func<void (*)(char const*), std::__1::allocator<void (*)(char const*)>, void (char const*)>::operator()(char const*&&)+35) (BuildId: 41e9e0cbb5db4bb6875333d66af6569f)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.746 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #05 pc 0001588f  /system/lib/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+79) (BuildId: 3abc3ce4c3b633a64b14c50cb931a64b)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.746 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #06 pc 00006dbd  /system/lib/liblog.so (__android_log_assert+285) (BuildId: bbac430fc6349b937996bb914e70c060)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.746 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #07 pc 000102a2  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::RefBase::decStrong(void const*) const+146) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.746 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #08 pc 00004de4  /system/lib/libheif.so (android::HeifDecoderImpl::decodeAsync()+436) (BuildId: 49a068f457bf8577f622fb97089c3c5d)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.746 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #09 pc 00004c23  /system/lib/libheif.so (android::HeifDecoderImpl::DecodeThread::threadLoop()+35) (BuildId: 49a068f457bf8577f622fb97089c3c5d)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.746 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #10 pc 00015116  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+374) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.747 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #11 pc 00098fee  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+174) (BuildId: 588f2cd5873ff4273bb25b25edb82606)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.747 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #12 pc 000147d9  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+457) (BuildId: ab4be013cda31e8c45d48aa23a89d0f8)
2021-01-09 14:12:53.747 19089-19089/? A/DEBUG:       #13 pc 000e6974  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+100) (BuildId: 6e3a0180fa6637b68c0d181c343e6806)
```

My understanding so far is that the HeifDecoderImpl is asked to decode image regions asynchronously (this is what "Subsampling Scale Image View" does, afaik), and in doing so attempts to free a resource too often, resulting in RefBase trying to decrease the strong reference count too often.

As an app programmer, I'm stumped and unsure if there's anything I can do here. Both HeifDecoderImpl  and RefBase appear to be core Android code. Do I need to review the "Subsampling Scale Image View" library? Any pointer is appreciated.

Comment: I can reproduce this in Android Studio with an emulator on API 30. The same code with the same images works perfectly fine with API 29.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears the error occurs due to the default Bitmap.Config of Bitmap.Config.RGB_565 used by SubsamplingScaleImageView (acutally in `SkiaImageDecoder.java`, part of that package). By switching to

```
SubsamplingScaleImageView.setPreferredBitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

the error disappears.

Comment: This is the correct solution. I don't understand why, because I tried to use BitmapRegionDecoder in own code, to load part of the same image, in the cycle, including recyclation and it not happens, even with Bitmap.Config.RGB_565. It looks like Android Bug to me.

Comment: Even better is probably to use Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE (since API 26)

Comment: @ATom did you have any problems setting `Bitmap.Config.HARDWARE`? It also seems to solve the problem for me, but I'm worried about breaking other things with it.